# What's this Advanced Dungeons & Dragons book?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification

I found this hard cover book and wasn't really sure on what it was. So I called a friend and he said it was "a rare edition" and that I could get quite a bit of money out of it. Is it actually rare and worth much?

[image: Front Cover]
[image: Inside Cover]

**the back cover and the inside are printed with the following:**

> Advanced Dungeons and Dragons Monster Manual. Special Reference Work. 4th Edition, August, 1979. Hard Cover.
>
> An alphabetical compendium of all the monsters found in advanced Dungeons & Dragons, including attacks, damage, special abilities, and descriptions.
>
> By Gary Gygax 1977, 1978 -TSR Games

Gently used. Binding is in perfect condition. No rips, tears, or folds.

> Over 350 Monsters This book provides a complete alphabetical listing of all "monsters" encountered in the various works which comprise the Advanced Dungeons & Dragons game system. It is an invaluable aid to players and dungeon masters alike!

Answer (score 36):

This isn't rare at all. This is the [Monster Manual from the 1st edition of Advanced Dungeons & Dragons](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/43361/monster-manual). It's worth about $5–$25 (US) on eBay, depending on condition. I got mine there for about $12, a few years ago, and prices haven't changed. Yours looks to be in fairly beaten condition, so you're unlikely to get anything much for it.

Although it's not valuable monetarily, it's a source of valuable insights into the history of D&D monsters, since this book is the first version of many monsters that appear in later editions.

Answer (score 10):

This is from the First Edition AD&D and is the most commonly found printing available. If you look at the title page, directly below where it says "Monster Manual", you'll see "4th Edition, August 1979" - that indicates you have one of the more commonly found versions of this book. Most have sold on eBay for around $8-$10 US. Sorry, it's older, but not worth a lot. If you can find a 1st printing, that would be a different story! :-)